# Filter XML data from XmlDataProvider using XPath

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xpath

I have a `xml` file like this:

```
<Organizations xmlns="">
    <Organization  Title ="dfs" Score="70">
        <Layer  Title ="lar"></Layer>
    </Organization>
    <Organization  Title ="srwrg" Score="70">
        <Layer  Title ="asdf"></Layer>
        <Layer  Title ="lfdkj"></Layer>
    </Organization>
</Organizations>
```

I use this file in my WPF project: (here is a Resource)

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="myData" Source="Data\farsDataOrganization.xml" XPath="//Organizations/Organization"/>

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCVS" >
        <CollectionViewSource.Source>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource myData}"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.Source>
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="@Title" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

I know how to make filter based on organization's `Title` or Layer's `Title`:

```
 XmlDataProvider p = (XmlDataProvider)this.FindResource("myData");
 p.XPath = string.Format("//Organizations/Organization[Layer[contains(@Title,\"{0}\")]]", this.layerNameFilter.Text);
```

**But** I want to filter these data based on both the organization's `Title` and Layer's `Title`. Is there any suggestion? How to change my `XPath` string so that I get the filter based on both of them?

**Edit**

I show these data on a `TreeView`:

```
 <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCVS}}">
     <TreeView.Resources>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Organization" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Layer}">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="340" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                 <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Title}" FontSize="13" Margin="0,0,0,-5"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
XmlDataProvider p = (XmlDataProvider)this.FindResource("myData");
p.XPath = string.Format("//Organizations/Organization[contains(@Title,\"{0}\")]/Layer[contains(@Title,\"{1}\")]", 
                        this.orgTitleFilter.Text, 
                        this.layerNameFilter.Text);
```

Comment: I show these data on a TreeView. this way Organization's Node will be hidden!

Comment: That XPath will select filtered Layers that are children of filtered Organizations.  If that's not what you want, you'll need to describe in better detail.

Comment: It seem this way just the Layers are selected. however I want to show Organization and Layers based on these filters.

Comment: How about if you transform the XML  so that it only contains the structures which pass the filters, then apply the binding as is?

Comment: This approach uses dynamic xpath binding, which I think is what you may be after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038693/apply-a-dynamic-xpath-expression-when-binding-xml-to-itemssource